# JOGL upside down rendering

Tags: java, jogl

I'm rendering an image with JOGL, using a `Texture` object, however it's being rendered upside down (picture: http://puu.sh/Q2QT). Any advice would be great, code follows:

```
private void renderImage(GL2 gl, String filename, int width, int height) {
  Texture texture = null;
  try {
    texture = TextureIO.newTexture(new File(this.getClass().getResource(filename).toURI()), true);
  }
  catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }

  int left = 0;
  int top = 0;

  texture.enable(gl);
  texture.bind(gl);

  gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_POLYGON);
  gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
  gl.glVertex2d(left, top);
  gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
  gl.glVertex2d(left + width, top);
  gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
  gl.glVertex2d(left + width, top + height);
  gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
  gl.glVertex2d(left, top + height);
  gl.glEnd();
  gl.glFlush();

  texture.disable(gl);
  texture.destroy(gl);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java and OpenGL have different ideas of the default orientation of a coordinate system. Java takes *y* = 0 as the *upper* rim of whatever the coordinate system is describing, going down from there. OpenGL takes *y* = 0 as the bottom of the reference rectangle. There are various locations places where you can flip the image. In your case, the simplest approach would be changing the association between scene and texture coordinates:

```
  gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
  gl.glVertex2d(left, top);
  gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
  gl.glVertex2d(left + width, top);
  gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
  gl.glVertex2d(left + width, top + height);
  gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
  gl.glVertex2d(left, top + height);
```

**EDIT:**
One [version of `newTexture`](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/texture/TextureIO.html#newTexture%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) provides a `mustFlipVertically` flag, but the one creating a texture from a file apparently does not. The “official” way to deal with different orientations is using [`getImageTexCoords`](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/texture/Texture.html#getImageTexCoords%28%29):

```
  TextureCoords tc = texture.getImageTexCoords();
  gl.glTexCoord2f(tc.left(), tc.top());
  gl.glVertex2d(left, top);
  gl.glTexCoord2f(tc.right(), tc.top());
  gl.glVertex2d(left + width, top);
  gl.glTexCoord2f(tc.right(), tc.bottom());
  gl.glVertex2d(left + width, top + height);
  gl.glTexCoord2f(tc.left(), tc.bottom());
  gl.glVertex2d(left, top + height);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however the first part of the answer hasn't worked (for some reason only a black square is being rendered)   With regards to the edit, the last parameter for the newTexture is whether or not mipmaps  are generated http://download.java.net/media/jogl/builds/archive/jsr-231-beta5/javadoc_public/com/sun/opengl/util/texture/TextureIO.html#newTexture(java.io.File, boolean)

Comment: @mikeythemissile, sorry, I read that flag in one version of `newTexture` and incorrectly assumed that all versions used it that way. Updated m answer accordingly. I'm still very much surprised that the original first answer doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

I usually read in image files as a BufferedImage, then flip them vertically with a handy function called ImageUtil.flipImageVertically(BufferedImage image). Here's an example:

```
for (int i= 0; i < imgPaths.length; i++){
        try {
            BufferedImage image= ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream ("/resources/"+imgPaths[i]));
            ImageUtil.flipImageVertically(image);

            textures[i]= AWTTextureIO.newTexture(glProfile, image, false);
            loadingBar.increaseProgress(1);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            say("Problem loading texture file " + imgPaths[i]);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Link to the Java documentation of this method: https://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/awt/ImageUtil.html#flipImageVertically(java.awt.image.BufferedImage)